# Handle config values in javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I have a PHP application which works with multiple partners. The way I do it is, based on a URL parameter I load a partner specific config file in PHP and then application gets customised for that partner. Like so:

```
//PHP Code
$partnerConfig = parse_ini_file($partnerCode.".ini");
```

Some of these config data also needs to be used in JavaScript. In order for that to happen I am currently loading PHP variables into JavaScript variables. Like so:

```
//js code
var partnerTZ = "<?php echo $partnerTimeZone ?>";
```

While this works, I think this is not a proper way to do it. Is there a way I can create partner specific configs in JavaScript and load them like I do in PHP. What is a good way to do handle this in JS?

Comment: Why don't you just `var partnerConfig = <?php echo json_encode($partnerConfig);?>;`? parseIni_file returns an assoc array so that should give you a valid JS object.

Comment: You could also make an AJAX request and load the config as JSON which would leave the HTML source cleaner.

Comment: Just another way. You can put that variable to hidden field in html (`eg. <input type="hidden" id="timezone" value="$partnerTimeZone" /> `) and then you can get value of that hidden field from your js code.

Answer (score -1):

in JavaScript config values is written in JSON format. you can load the json formatted file. if you're using node you can just

```
var config = require(<filepath of the config.>);
```

for more information about JSON.
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_intro.asp

Comment: "in JavaScript config values is written in JSON format" — The config files the OP is dealing with are in INI format, not JSON.

Comment: "if you're using node" — They are using script elements in HTML documents generated by PHP.

Comment: "w3schools" — [no, just no](http://www.w3fools.com). (Let's see how that particular example racks up…"When exchanging data between a browser and a server, the data can only be text." wrong. "we can convert any JavaScript object into JSON" wrong. (And then we get to the code, oh dear).